# Extern crate inside main method; module::Type vs main::module::Type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build [diesel_demo](https://github.com/sgrif/diesel_demo) with a stable compiler, not a nightly. Part of the `build.rs`, modified by me, is:

```
fn main() {
    extern crate syntex;
    extern crate diesel_codegen_syntex;
    extern crate dotenv_codegen;

    use std::env;
    use std::path::Path;

    let out_dir = env::var_os("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
    let mut registry = syntex::Registry::new();
    diesel_codegen_syntex::register(&mut registry);
    dotenv_codegen::register(&mut registry);

    let src = Path::new("src/lib.in.rs");
    let dst = Path::new(&out_dir).join("lib.rs");

    registry.expand("", &src, &dst).unwrap();
}
```

When building with Rust 1.11, I get an error:

```
error: mismatched types [E0308]
    diesel_codegen_syntex::register(&mut registry);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `&mut syntex::Registry`
note:    found type `&mut main::syntex::Registry`
error: mismatched types [E0308]
    dotenv_codegen::register(&mut registry);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `&mut syntex::Registry`
note:    found type `&mut main::syntex::Registry`
```

What is the `main::syntex::Registry` type, where did the compiler get it and why it is not the same thing as `syntex::Registry`?

To reproduce this issue you need change `Cargo.toml` of `disel_demo`:

```
-default = ["nightly"]
+default = ["with-syntex"]
```

and replace `diesel_codegen` with `diesel_codegen_syntex` in `build.rs`

It looks like there are two `syntex::Registry` types. I have no idea why, but because `diesel_codegen_syntex` depends on `syntex`, there may be two different versions of `syntex`?

Comment: @kennytm Actually I am insteresting what is going on if `extern crate` inside the function, because of I didn't meet such construction before.

Comment: Do you get two different versions of `syntex` in the `Cargo.lock` file?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Yes, two versions of syntex and `syntex_something`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, Cargo allows several versions of a crate in the same project, which can happen if different dependencies require different versions.  If so, they will be treated as separate sets of modules and types - otherwise common versions use the same instance.

At time of writing, diesel_codegen_syntex seems to want version syntex 0.42.0, where the build.rs is asking for version 0.38.0.  This means that the registry instantiated in build.rs's `main()` is *not* compatible with the type expected by `diesel_codegen_syntex::register()`.

The fact that one is `main::syntex::Registry` is because the crate is imported into `main`'s scope rather than the global module/crate root; it's scoped like `use` or `let`.  If you move the `extern crate syntex;` to the top level outside main the types are still different, but confusingly the visible names are the same; the error then says:

```
build.rs:12:37: 12:50 note: expected type `&mut syntex::Registry`
build.rs:12:37: 12:50 note:    found type `&mut syntex::Registry`
```

You can get around this problem by changing the version in the `[build-dependencies]` section of Cargo.toml to match; change:

```
syntex = { version = "0.38.0", optional = true }
```

to:

```
syntex = { version = "0.42.0", optional = true }
```

That gets `build.rs` to compile for me (it doesn't get as far as linking because I don't have the postgres libraries installed, though, so I can't guarantee there aren't futher issues).

Comment: Sorry for not clear question. I know how to fix problem. What I do not know, what is going on from language point of view. How extern crate inside function pollete name space, what rules to assign names to the same types with different version?

Comment: I've made an edit which I hope will help.  The types are different because they're from different versions/instances of the same crate - nothing to do with "extern crate" being in main.